# Determinant of a matrix that has 0 on the diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

$$ 
\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&1&\cdots&1&1 \\ 
1&0&x&\cdots&x&x \\ 
1&x&0&\cdots&x&x \\ 
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots \\ 
1&x&x&\cdots&0&x \\ 
1&x&x&\cdots&x&0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I have tried to solve it differently, mostly I tried to make a lower triangle matrix. Usually I use way with lambda, but I still don't have right answer

Comment: do you know the eigenvalues of a ( square symmetric) matrix with all entries $1 \; \; ?$   Take that, subtract off the identity matrix, what are the eigenvalues now?  Finally, what if you multiply it all by some $x ?$  That is what your lower right block is doing, Not the whole problem, but a start

Comment: meanwhile, starting over, you could take your original matrix  and just add $xI$  to it, $x$ times the identity, so that most rows are the same, and these eigenvalues are easy  to find. Same as my first comment, how do the eigenvalues of your original matrix compare?

Comment: @WillJagy, Well, actually this way may be used, but I don't think it's my case. Probably I need to use matrix properties, The Gauss method or method when we add 1 number to the whole matrix and then find out the determinate of a new one and use a special relation. Using this methods I don't find a good way to solve the determinate.

Comment: Have you tried computing a few small cases? The pattern seems pretty simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that we are looking at the $n\times n$ matrix. This works for all $n \geq 2$. I also use $|\cdot|$ to mean determinant.

One of the most useful facts for this problem is that if you add or subtract a multiple of a row (or column) from a different row (or column) then the determinant does not change. Subtracting the last row from all but itself and the first one has

\begin{equation}
 \left | \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 1 \\
   1 & 0 & x & \cdots & x & x \\
   1 & x & 0 & \cdots & x & x \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
   1 & x & x & \cdots & 0 & x \\
   1 & x & x & \cdots & x & 0 \\
 \end{bmatrix} \right | = 
 \left | \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 1 \\
   0 & -x & 0 & \cdots & 0 & x \\
   0 & 0 & -x & \cdots & 0 & x \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -x & x \\
   1 & x & x & \cdots & x & 0 \\
 \end{bmatrix} \right |
\end{equation}
Now add the second to second-to-last rows to the last row
\begin{equation} 
 \left | \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 1 \\
   0 & -x & 0 & \cdots & 0 & x \\
   0 & 0 & -x & \cdots & 0 & x \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -x & x \\
   1 & x & x & \cdots & x & 0 \\
 \end{bmatrix} \right | = 
 \left | \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 1 \\
   0 & -x & 0 & \cdots & 0 & x \\
   0 & 0 & -x & \cdots & 0 & x \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -x & x \\
   1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & (n-2)x \\
 \end{bmatrix} \right |
\end{equation}
Now add $1/x$ of the second to second-to-last rows to the first row
\begin{equation} 
 \left | \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 1 \\
   0 & -x & 0 & \cdots & 0 & x \\
   0 & 0 & -x & \cdots & 0 & x \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -x & x \\
   1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & (n-2)x \\
 \end{bmatrix} \right | =
 \left | \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & n-1 \\
   0 & -x & 0 & \cdots & 0 & x \\
   0 & 0 & -x & \cdots & 0 & x \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -x & x \\
   1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & (n-2)x \\
 \end{bmatrix} \right | 
\end{equation}
Now add $-x/(n-1)$ of the first row to the second to second-to-last rows and $-x(n-2)/(n-1)$ of the first row to the last
\begin{equation} 
 \left | \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & n-1 \\
   0 & -x & 0 & \cdots & 0 & x \\
   0 & 0 & -x & \cdots & 0 & x \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -x & x \\
   1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & (n-2)x \\
 \end{bmatrix} \right | =
 \left | \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & n-1 \\
   0 & -x & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & -x & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -x & 0 \\
   1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
 \end{bmatrix} \right |
\end{equation}
Swapping rows also flips the sign of the determinant. Swapping the first and the last gives
\begin{equation}
 \left | \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & n-1 \\
   0 & -x & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & -x & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -x & 0 \\
   1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
 \end{bmatrix} \right | = -
 \left | \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & -x & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & -x & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -x & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & n-1 \\
 \end{bmatrix} \right |
\end{equation}
and we can calculate that the determinant of a diagonal matrix is the product of the diagonal terms and therefore
\begin{equation} 
 - \left | \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & -x & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & -x & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -x & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & n-1 \\
 \end{bmatrix} \right | = -(n-1)(-x)^{n-2}
\end{equation}

Comment: In step 3, you should note that if $x = 0$ and $n > 2$ then the matrix has repeated rows, so determinant $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Call your matrix $A$ and let $J$ be the matrix of ones. The eigenvalues of $J$ are $n,0,\ldots,0$, so the eigenvalues of $J-I$ are $n-1,-1,\ldots,-1$. Thus $\det(J-I) = (-1)^{n-1}(n-1)$. Now compute the determinant of the matrix $$x(J-I) = \begin{bmatrix}  0 & x &  \cdots & x & x \\ x & 0 & \cdots & x & x \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ x & x & \cdots & 0 & x \\ x & x & \cdots & x & 0\end{bmatrix}$$ in two different ways. On one hand, $\det(x(J-I)) = x^n\det(J - I) = x^n(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)$. On the other hand, by factoring out an $x$ from the first row and column we see $\det(x(J-I)) = x^2 \det(A)$. Equating our two expressions reveals that $\det(A) = x^{n-2}(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)$.