# Determinant of a matrix that has 0 on the diagnols and have sums of ai,j in it

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

$$ 
\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&1&-&1 \\ 
1&0& a_{1}+a_{2} &-&a_{1}+a_{n}\\ 
1&a_{2}+a_{1}&0&-&a_{2}+a_{n}\\
 -&-&-&-&-\\ 
1&a_{n}+a_{1}&a_{n}+a_{2}&-&0 \end{pmatrix}
$$

I need to find a determinate, which looks like that.
Connected to my classes and methods that we use recently
probably I need to use matrix properties, The Gauss method.
I have tried to use them, but I don't find correct answer. It will be fine if I get a tiangle matrix or diagonal[image]

Comment: Please state your question clearly.

Comment: For context, see also the [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4883266/determinant-of-a-matrix-that-has-0-on-the-diagonal).

Comment: What happens if you replace the $k$-th row with that row minus $a_{k-1}$ times the top row? How does that operation affect the determinant? What about replacing the $k$-th column with that column minus $a_{k-1}$ times the first column?

Comment: @PaulSinclair, I can get $$\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&1&-&1 \\ 
1&-a_{1}&0&-&0\\ 
1&0&-a_{2}&-&0\\
 -&-&-&-&-\\ 
1&0&0&-&-a_{n} \end{pmatrix}$$ or even $$\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&1&-&1 \\ 
0&-a_{1}&0&-&0\\ 
0&0&-a_{2}&-&0\\
 -&-&-&-&-\\ 
1&0&0&-&-a_{n} \end{pmatrix}$$, bit I don't see the way to get triangle without 1 on (1,n) place

Comment: I thought you needed to find the *determinant*, not a triangular matrix. And are you sure those are correct?

Comment: @PaulSinclair, yes, I need to find determinate, but if I have triangle matrix, I'll find it easily, so I try to get this one.

Comment: There are *other ways* of calculating determinants than triangular matrices. Even Cramer's rule is not unreasonable when the only off-diagonal elements are in the first row/column.

Comment: And are you really, really sure those are correct?

Comment: @PaulSinclair, I'm absolutely sure in deteminate, which I wrote in my question. If you ask about modified - I subtracted 1 column from each k column multiplied by ak and get $$\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&1&-&1 \\ 
1&-a_{1}& a_{1} &-&a_{1}\\ 
1&a_{2}&-a_{2}&-&a_{2}\\
 -&-&-&-&-\\ 
1&a_{n}&a_{n}&-&-a_{n} \end{pmatrix}$$, then I subtracted from each k row1 row multiplied by ak and get $$\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&1&-&1 \\ 
1&-2a_{1}& 0 &-&0\\ 
1&0&-2a_{2}&-&0\\
 -&-&-&-&-\\ 
1&0&0&-&-2a_{n} \end{pmatrix}$$. P.S. I realised I wrote -ak instead of -2ak, but it's not important for general idea I suppose...

Comment: That and you changed the upper left corner from $0$ to $1$ was why I wanted you to re-examine. It might not be important for the "general idea", but for this specific problem, they would absolutely wreck your answer if not corrected. Note that if you divide every row but the top by the appropriate $\frac 2{a_k}$, this divides the determinant by $2^na_1a_2\dots a_n$. In the resulting matrix, you can then add each of the other rows to the top row to get a lower-triangular matrix.

Comment: And by the way, if what you want is the determinant, then suggesting a different way of calculating the same number does not in any way "modify" the problem. It just suggests that you could solve it by a different approach than the one that wasn't working for you.